# Korrekte Schreibung von Straßennamen

Tags: typography

Verkehrsflächenbezeichnungen bestehen in der Regel aus einem Grundwort (-straße, -gasse, -platz, -ring, -weg et cetera) und einem Bestimmungswort zur näheren Kennzeichnung der Verkehrsfläche. Straßennamen, welche mehrteilige Personennamen sind, werden dabei (mittlerweile auch in Österreich) mit Bindestrich geschrieben:

> Johann-Nepomuk-Berger-Platz
>
> Maria-Theresien-Straße
>
> Tierarzt-Ludwig-Müllner-Weg

Mein Problem ist nun ein Straßenname, in dem ein *&* vorkommt: Schreibe ich

> Mustermann & Söhne Straße
>
> Mustermann & Söhne-Straße
>
> Mustermann-&-Söhne-Straße
>
> Mustermann-und-Söhne-Straße

Oder ganz anders? Eine amtliche Schreibweise habe ich leider nicht gefunden.

Comment: Laut den [amtlichen Regeln](http://www.duden.de/sites/default/files/downloads/amtliche_Regelungen.pdf), § 50 setzt man "einen
Bindestrich zwischen allen Bestandteilen mehrteiliger Zusammensetzungen, deren erste Bestandteile aus Eigennamen bestehen". Das würde bedeuten, dass der dritte Vorschlag **Mustermann-&-Söhne-Straße** richtig ist.

Comment: Danke für den Link. Typographisch ist das leider sehr unschön, aber das ist wohl nicht zu ändern.

Comment: Typografisch finde ich den vierten Vorschlag **Mustermann-und-Söhne-Straße** deutlich schöner.

Comment: @IQV Das hängt wohl von der Definition von *Bestandteil* ab. Der Eigenname ist ja *Mustermann & Söhne" und nicht 3 Eigennamen "Mustermann", "&" und "Söhne".

Comment: Der einzig reale Strassenname, der mir einfällt und der nach deinem Muster geformt ist, ist die *Thurn-und-Taxis-Strasse*, die es in Süddeutschland in vielen Gemeinden gibt und die nach den amtlichen Regeln auch genau so zu schreiben ist.

Comment: @tofro Bei den Beispielen des Regelwerk findet sich "am Lago-di-Como-seitigen Abhang". Dort ist auch "Lago di Como" der Eigenname und dort werden überall Bindestriche gesetzt. Aber du hast recht: eindeutig ist es nicht.

Comment: Falls du von einer bereits existierenden Straße redest, hast du in diesem Fall ein Problem: Laut Wikipedia kommt es gerade bei älteren Straßen auch vor, dass die bisherige Schreibweise einer Straße beibehalten wurde, nachdem sich die entsprechenden Rechtschreibregeln geändert haben. Wahrscheinlich hätten auch die Stadtverwaltungen etwas Spielraum bei der Schreibweise des Namens, wenn eine Straße neu benannt wird. Die laut Rechtschreibregeln korrekte Schreibweise wäre dann falsch, während die laut Rechtschreibregeln falsche Schreibweise korrekt wäre.

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt keine eindeutige Festlegung. Verschiedene DIN-Normen machen zu diesem Thema widersprüchliche Aussagen. Einesteils soll das et-Zeichen nur in Firmennamen verwendet werden und sonst durch *und* ersetzt werden, andererseits soll auch das *&* in Zusammensetzungen mit Bindestrich durchgekoppelt werden.

Das führt zu uneinheitlicher Anwendung, wie das Beispiel *Ohrenstein-&-Koppel-Straße* in Potsdam zeigt, wenn man sich das in einschlägigen Internet-Suchmaschinen in der Trefferliste anschaut.<sup>[(1)](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=ohrenstein%20und%20koppel%20stra%C3%9Fe)</sup>